# react js float clear property

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was trying to design this:

[image]

the css used for this is:

```
.body {
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.one {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
p {
  clear:right;
}
```

but if i use this code the output is:
[image]

but it works fine if i remove

```
p {
clear:right;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? You seem to have solved the problem, and your solution is correct.

Comment: why does it work fine without it and if i add it it doesnt work. @AHaworth

Comment: When you add clear you are saying to the system that the element must come after the specified (left,right or both) previous floated elements. That is what clear is for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Answer (score 0):

The clear property controls the flow next to floated elements. when you set `clear:right;` it will be pushed below the right floated elements;